# Find the Integral, $ I_{1,1I}=\int \frac{x\arcsin{x}}{c\arcsin{k}+\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, integration-by-parts

$$
I:=\int\arcsin\left(c+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}{\arcsin{k}}\right)\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $c$ and $k$ are constants with respect to $x$. Euler lets
$$
I=\int \ln{(iu+\sqrt{1-u^2})}\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $u:=c+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}{\arcsin{k}}$.
$I$ is separable:
$$
I=\int\ln{(u)}\mathrm{d}x + \int\ln{(i+\sqrt{\frac{1}{u^2}-1})}\mathrm{d}x
$$
The first of the sum of integrals, $I_{1}$, is found by naming $u$:
$$
I_{1}=\int\ln{(c+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}{\arcsin{k}})}\mathrm{d}x
$$
$$
=\int\ln{(c\arcsin{k}+\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x})}\mathrm{d}x-\int\ln{(\arcsin{k})}\mathrm{d}x
$$
Thus,
$$
I_{1,2}=-x\ln\arcsin{k}
$$
Per partes gives:
$$
I_{1,1}=x\ln{(u\arcsin{k})}-\int \frac{x\arcsin{x}}{c\arcsin{k}+\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}\mathrm{d}x
$$
Substitution provides
$$
I_{1,1I}=\int \frac{e^{2y}\tan{e^y}}{c\arcsin{k}\cos{e^y}+\cos^2{e^y} + e^y\sin{e^y}\cos{e^y}}\mathrm{d}y
$$
where $y:=\ln{\arcsin{x}}$. Substitution also provides
$$
I_{1,1I}=\int \frac{y\sin{y}\cos{y}}{c\arcsin{k}+\cos{y}+y\sin{y}}\mathrm{d}y
$$
where $y:=\arcsin{x}$. Where 
$$
J:= \int \frac{c\arcsin{k}}{c\arcsin{k}+\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
K:=\int \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{c\arcsin{k}+\sqrt{1-x^2} + x\arcsin{x}}\mathrm{d}x,
$$
$$
I_{1,1I}+J+K = x
$$
I am trying to find $I_{1,1I}$, but my substitutions, per partes intgration, and additive integration techniques are not working.

Comment: Maple can't do this integral.

Comment: Are you sure it exists

Comment: No. I suspect that it does. Each time I think I can go no further, I find a way to resolve some part of it.

Comment: looks hopeless to me